# How to visualize grd files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation, diva-gis

How to visualize grd files in the software QGIS?

Answer (score 9):

There are at least two formats with .grd/.gri extension. One is Golden Software grid - GDAL can easily handle it, so simply open it through Add Raster Layer, as [Didier Blavet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23015/12768) suggested.

But there is also DIVA-GIS grid format. I found a [maillist entry](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Cannot-add-any-GRD-data-tp4128437p4128448.html) saying that only DIVA-GIS can open it. So you have basically two options: you can get and install DIVA, open the data in it and save them in a different format. Or you can find the same data in a different format. For example, elevation data provided in DIVA grid format on [DIVA website](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) are the same as those on [SRTM](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp).

Big thanks to Goyo from OSGeo community, 99% of my post is derived from what he wrote!

Comment: I justed tested with the Togo landuse map, and the ZIP file included a .vrt file as well. Use that to open the map in GRASS GIS, QGIS, etc since they read the .vrt file via GDAL.

Answer (score 5):

i think that you can visualize a grd file (ie a grid file) as a raster layer. if you try the menu layer add raster then you will fin several types of grid files. i my case i opened golden software grid (with extension grd) with this menu. After that if the file can be opened you can change the colors, choose a transparent color etc ...
best regards

Comment: There are several (slightly?) different formats with .grd extension, and QGIS can open only some of these. I don't know which format exactly is on Diva GIS, but I can't open it this way, as well as the guy who asked [another question on this topic](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24833/12768).

Answer (score 3):

I have stumbled on this set of question and answers because I have been handed a data set from 2004 that has the 'grd extension. QGIS 2.14.4 has not been able to open them through the usual GDAL magic.
I was able to open them by changing the file extension to .csv and importing as a text layer and as a spreadsheet layer.
So I'm just adding to the the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some .grd files are actually [netCDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) array data, typically created by [GMT](https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/gmt/). Import of netCDF have been [discussed here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=netcdf%20QGIS) earlier. Sometimes, the cell order is reversed and needs to be flipped or transposed. Some plugins wouldn't recognise .grd files, but just saving the ending to .nc can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with mag data from the USGS right now and it came in this format. I was able to open the files with Geosoft Viewer and convert them to GeoTIFFs, there are some other formats that Geosoft Viewer can output if you have other requirements. I know qgis can open .ers files as well, that is an option for exporting.

Geosoft viewer is available at https://www.geosoft.com/products/geosoft-viewer. This is also discussed in a thread at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geosoft-Grid-Files-td5278481.html. They suggest that .gxf may also be an option for exporting.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you can download from DIVA GIS has a .vrt file which can be open with QGIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QGIS plugin grd_loader for this:

[grd_loader plugin](https://github.com/Loop3D/grd_loader)