# How to load and view .gri and .grd files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, diva-gis

An online GIS Repository called DIVA-GIS (http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) offers data in three formats - ERSI files, "DIVA gridfiles", and DBF files

The DIVA gridfiles have extensions .gri and .grd

How can these file types be opened in qGIS?  The "Add Raster" menu option does not seem to work

Comment: see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23002/how-to-visualize-grd-files-in-quantum-gis

Comment: Are you trying to use the 'add raster layer' dialog? .GRD files are a standard type that QGIS can open, through the GDAL library.

Comment: I don't actually have the answer (and no enough points to comment..) but I would like to add that the R raster package also save in this .gri/.grd format and it is not possible to open them with either grass or qgis, and surely not with the option suggested in the linked comment (as golden software format).

Comment: I have just answered this question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/93209/12768).