# Viewing .grd and .gri file format in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, diva-gis

I have downloaded a file from DIVAGIS, the landcover map of India, and it is in the format of .grd and .gri file.

How can i view these files in ArcGIS 10.1?

Comment: This is a QGIS Q&A but may nevertheless be worth looking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23002

Comment: 10.1 supports .grd: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/04/17/grd-and-grc-files-now-supported-in-arcgis-10-1/

Comment: add data button

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the grid file into Ascii using DivaGIS by export grid file option from Data menu in DivaGIS. The Ascii can open in ArcGIS