# Displaying GRD and GRD.gi files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo-discover

I am trying to display GRD and GRD.gi files in QGIS with no luck. The files seem to load fine using Mapinfo, but mapinfo doesnt allow you to convert to geotiff. Any ideas?

This is a geophysics data set from a government website dating back to the 1990's

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23002/how-to-visualize-grd-files-in-qgis

Comment: Are they potentially **Geosoft Oasis Montaj** grid (grd) and its associated projection (.grd.gi) files? You may want to try its free viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this QGIS plugin to load a Geosoft GRD file:

[QGIS Plugin grd_loader](https://github.com/Loop3D/grd_loader)