# Format from which I can export from Geosoft and add to QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, geosoft

I have several .GRD files that I am able to open in Geosoft viewer with no issue but they will not open in QGIS. I have tried to export them from geosoft viewer but there are so many file types and none I have tried have been able import into QGIS. I have read multiple places that the Export from geosoft works but I cannot seem to get it to output a usable format.

Comment: Is that vector or raster data ? if vector try to export to one of these https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html if raster try one of these https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html

Comment: Also how did you try to open your data in QGIS, maybe the data is good but your procedure is wrong...

Comment: Can you point us to a sample file so we can try? Possibly if the file ends in ".grd" then QGIS is trying to load it as a different sort of grid file, since that extension is probably used by more than one file format...

Comment: Possibly related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23002/how-to-visualize-grd-files-in-qgis

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://qgis-user.osgeo.narkive.com/f5ASyLaj/geosoft-grid-files suggests convert to GXF format...

Comment: sample data please - normally globalmapper will open any grd format thern export the to asc or geotiff to open in QGIS.